# Hosting Java Webservice on Amazon Linux AMI 2013.03

Tags: java, linux, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I am given an Amazon Linux AMI 2013.03 instance with dns address like this: `ec2-22-11-111-105.compute-1.amazonaws.com` on which I have to host a java web service.
I am connecting to it as ec2-user.
I have installed tomcat6 server on it by this command: `sudo yum install tomcat6 tomcat6-webapps` and place my `WebService.war` file in the `\usr\share\tomcat6\webapps` folder. And then I have started the tomcat server as `sudo service tomcat6 start`.
The tomcat is running on port 8080 and I have already got the port 8080 opened.
So I am now trying to connect to this port from some other machine by this url: `http://ec2-22-11-111-105.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080` but I am not able to connect to it although the tomcat server is running.
What am I doing wrong? How can I make it work ?

Comment: Can you connect locally?  Check the AWS firewall settings in addition to any firewall on the server itself?

Comment: I dont know how to connect locally from terminal? is there any command?

Comment: localhost:8080. Do you have this machine in a security group with 8080 closed?

Comment: I think you are using a cloud service, thus the host ec2-22-11-111-105.compute-1.amazonaws.com might be hosting multiple servers on the same address, Therefore you need to connect using a domain that they provided like I was provided http://wood-cut.rhcloud.com domain for ec2-54-224-184-231.compute-1.amazonaws.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The likeliest problem is that the security group for this EC2 machine does not allow access on port 8080.
Have a look here for more details:
[Create and Configure Your Amazon EC2 Security Group](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/wah/getting-started-security-group.html)

Once you modify the security group, the change is applied immediately so you do not need to start a new EC2 machine.